# How do i bind custom filter with html template (Input type)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Lets say i have,

`<input type="text" name="classDuration" data-ng-model="ClassDuration" />`

and i have customer filter `formatDuromation` defined in my customer filter JavaScript file which convert number to `hh:mm` format.

How i can use/bind custom filter with my input file in html?

Answer (score 0):

> In HTML Template Binding

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}
```

> In JavaScript

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)
```

Read this documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: Did not get how i can use "{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}" with my input example

Answer (score 0):

In HTML Template Binding

```
  {{(Companies| filter:{CompanyID:2})[0].CompanyName }}
```